# Problem with multiple navigationcontrollers in a tabbarcontroller that points to one detail view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have an app that have one tabbarcontroller that contains a navigationcontroller for each tab. Every navigationcontroller ends up at a view controller with the name DetailViewController. But if the user navigates to DetailViewController on one tab and then switches tab and navigates to DetailViewController there too, and the app crashes with the error:

```
2011-08-19 21:14:45.257 Kluringar[4368:ef03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

The code that pushes DetailViewController looks like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    kluringIdString = [[kluringar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

The code that gets the data from the database and adds it to the array looks like this:

```
-(void) getAllRowsFromTableNamed {
    //—-retrieve rows—- 
    NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Kluringar ORDER BY rubrik"];    
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;    
    kluringar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *kluringarDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {     
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *kluringId = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);           
            NSString *kluringIdStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: kluringId];
            char *rubrik = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);          
            NSString *rubrikStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: rubrik];
            //---add items--- 
            [kluringarDictionary setValue:kluringIdStr forKey:@"id"];
            [kluringarDictionary setValue:rubrikStr forKey:@"rubrik"];
            [kluringar addObject:[kluringarDictionary copy]];       
        }   
        //—-deletes the compiled statement from memory—-        
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);        
    }   
}
```

Here is a link to the storyboard: [storyboard](http://alanihre.se/storyboard.png)

Thans in advance! :)

Comment: IIRC, storyboarding is part of iOS 5 and, as such, still under NDA. So you should probably post this question over at http://devforums.apple.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to access an array in this line

```
kluringIdString = [[kluringar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
```

that should have multiple elements but it doesn't.  I would suggest you look through your code and see how many elements are added to the kluringar array.

Comment: Right now I have 10 objects in the array that is dictionaries that contains 2 keys each.

Comment: With 10 objects in the array is the app is still crashing?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question so you can see the code where I add the objects to the array.

Comment: Try commenting out line starting with kluringIdString.  Then above it place NSLog(@"%i", [kluringar count]);

Comment: Strange i get the following messages in the log but the app does not crash.                                                             2011-08-19 22:48:28.388 Kluringar[5928:ef03] 10
2011-08-19 22:48:36.715 Kluringar[5928:ef03] 2
2011-08-19 22:48:41.032 Kluringar[5928:ef03] 2
2011-08-19 22:48:43.102 Kluringar[5928:ef03] 3

Comment: How many items do you have in your table view?  Also is the kluringar array supplying those items to the table view?

Comment: In the table in the fist tab where every object is displayed there is always 10 items. In the second tab where there is some categories and when the user clicks a category the app navigates to a table where the objects for that category is displayed. And finally there is a tableview in the last tab that displays favorites. I have compared the data with the database and it is correct. But that is maybe because the table is never reloaded?

Comment: The reason your app is crashing when you select a row is because the kluringar array is not in synch with the number of items in the table view.  In the line kluringIdString change indexPath.row to 1.  See if it crashes.

Comment: No is does not crash. But in the first view i get the first row in the DetailViewController but when i switch with and select a row and go back to the first tab I don´t get the first row anymore and I can see in the log that the kluringar array only contains three objects.

Comment: It is really hard to diagnose your problem without seeing all your code.  My best guess is you have to find out what is causing your kluringar array items to change. Look at the code that is accessing or adding objects to the kluringar array.

Comment: Here is my whole project but I will take a look at the code [link](http://alanihre.se/Arkiv.zip)

Comment: I can't run your project.  I didn't even realize you were on iOS5.  You have to post this on devforums.apple.com.  iOS5 is still under a NDA.

Comment: I also updated your code in your getAllRowsFromTableNamed method.  Your NSMutableDictionary was never getting released.  You also didn't need to send copy to it when adding it to the array.

Comment: The changes are still pending.  It has to be peer reviewed before the code is updated.